# How to use organic supports in the slicer?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, support-structures, prusaslicer

How to use organic supports in PrusaSlicer or Cura? I heard that it is possible, but I can’t find this option in these slicers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, PrusaSlicer organic tree support isn't available to the public yet. PrusaSlicer is rumored to use the same code as the Pull request made by Thomas Rahm on his Cura fork who started working on this code around 2020.

The "organic" tree support contributed by Thomas Rahm is also available in the 5.3.0-alpha+xmas Cura version in Cura, which showcases that new tree support. You  can find more information in the article [Special alpha: new (Xmas) tree supports for UltiMaker Cura](https://ultimaker.com/learn/cura-christmas-tree-support)

Full disclosure I'm one of the Cura developers.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE.3DP. Thanks for editing the post and clarifying... sorry for any mis-understanding :-)

Comment: Hi, thanks for having me, I could also have been a bit more clear in my initial answer, but glad to know that the mis-understanding has been cleared up

Answer (score 5):

As Cura is mentioned in the question, it could be solved using Cura. The only organic support in Cura is called `Tree` as option of `Support Structure` in UltiMaker Cura's advanced options.

[image]

This option works best if you want support, but do not want Cura to build it on top of your end product (`Support Placement` -> `Touching Buildplate`).

[image]

This would lead to the generation of an organic like structure for the support structure:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It looks like Organic supports is not available yet. That’s why it is not in the slicer.